# Cannot open .jar files with java installed (windows 11)

Tags: java, windows, mips, mars-simulator

Environment: Windows 11
Problem: cannot open .jar file(the MARS assembly language simulator)

Hello, I am currently trying to install the MARS assembly language simulator. It is a .jar file so I downloaded java to open it. However, I still can't open the file even with java downloaded.
I checked if java was installed using my cmd:
[Command prompt showing java successfully installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrC3x.png)

I tried double-clicking it did not work. So I right-clicked it to open with other apps. But I did not see java in the given options.
[Cannot find the java option to open the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEORT.png)

Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: You posted the same image twice. It shows some kind of zip app inviting to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use your prompt
CD into the directory with the jar
then execute
java -jar Mars.jar
...any more troubles , open file properties tab with right click on the jar and check permissions to execute the file.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Java usually means installing a JVM, which is a *Java Virtual Machine*. You won't be able to launch files from a Windows context menu like this, because "Java" is not a program that opens files.

Instead you need to:

- Either a terminal and call `javaw.exe` with the parameters `-jar` and your `.jar`-file. *E.g.:*

```
C:\your\java\binaries\javaw.exe -jar -SomeJarFile.jar
```

- Or add the Java installation to your environment variables, then you can call `javaw.exe` without providing some specific path

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem for the nth time.

There are numerous threads with helpful answers, but they tend not to mention that if you already tried to "Open With" you will also have to delete `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jar`.

Here is a script to solve this problem, combining all the actions needed for it to work (call it anything with a `.cmd` extension):

```
@echo off
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jar" /f
assoc .jar=jarfile
ftype jarfile="<FULL_PATH_TO_JAVAW.EXE>" -jar "%1" %*
pause
```

Don't forget to replace `<FULL_PATH_TO_JAVAW.EXE>` with YOUR actual javaw.exe path. For example: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin\javaw.exe`.